# Class does add via jquery, but doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css

So my jquery is

```
var offCanvass = function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.js-fh5co-nav-toggle', function(event){

        var $this = $(this);

        $('#fh5co-offcanvass').toggleClass('fh5co-awake');
        $('#fh5co-page, #fh5co-menu, #fh5co-clients, #form').toggleClass('fh5co-sleep');

        if ( $('#fh5co-offcanvass').hasClass('fh5co-awake') ) {
            $this.addClass('active');
        } else {
            $this.removeClass('active');
        }
        event.preventDefault();

    });
};
```

And the problem page is https://viid.su, when the menu is opened everything should move away, and yeah everything moves to the except the bar where you can shorten a link! What is wrong here ? The class fh5co-sleep is added but nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of the page. `style.css` contans `#fh5co-menu.fh5co-sleep` & `#fh5co-page.fh5co-sleep`

But, your element is `#fh5co-clients`. You should add `#fh5co-clients.fh5co-sleep` along with the relevant CSS and it should work.

Comment: I solved it myself but you are the only one who tried to help so thank you :)